# can not import from itertools izip on Python 3

Tags: python, python-itertools, izip

On my project, I'm trying to import izip library, but is not working

```
from itertools import izip
from random    import normalvariate, random
from datetime  import timedelta, datetime
```

and I get this error:

```
from itertools import izip
ImportError: cannot import name 'izip'
```

but am only trying to import the library to my python 3 project

Comment: In Python 3, the builtin `zip` (and `map` and `filter`) already return iterators instead of full lists, so `itertools.izip` (and `imap` and `ifilter`) became obsolete.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In `python 3` just use `zip` instead of `izip` without importing anything.